# Android Studio Webview with Chrome?

Tags: java, android, webview

I want to show a website in Android Studio with the web-view. The Website doesn´t load but there is a message:

TO use this site: Please use a standard-compliants web browser such as Safari 4.0+, Chrome or Firefox 15.0+, JavaScript must be enabled to use this site.

And I have enabled Javascript.

Do you know what I can do that the website loads anyway?

```
WebView w = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.w);
WebSettings ws = w.getSettings();
    ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    w.loadUrl("https://www.supremenewyork.com/mobile/");
```

Comment: Show your code!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add user-agent string like this :

```
ws.setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.71 Safari/537.36");
```

You can get a list of user agents here :
https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/

Comment: But now it is just possible to see the web version. What do I have to change to see the mobile Version?

Comment: It's weird cause I see the mobile version even on my desktop browser. Maybe try with a mobile chrome user-agent : Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; SM-G930V Build/NRD90M) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.125 Mobile Safari/537.36